# Create a meeting using Windows Live REST API

Tags: c#, rest, windows-phone-8, windows-live

I'm trying to create a meeting on Outlook.com using the Windows Live REST API (for Windows Phone 8).
I'm able to create a calendar entry with all the basic fields of event object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243648.aspx#event), but I can't find a way to add the organizer and the attendees to the event.

There is a way to make that, using any key not specified for the event structure? 
For example I saw that in the contact object can contains a user object, even if not specified into the structure (it is written under the table).

This is the structure I used for now: it works, maybe could be usefull for someone else (as I said, it is missing of organizer and attendees):

```
IDictionary<string, object> appointment = new Dictionary<string, object>();
appointment.Add("name", "event");
appointment.Add("description", "a meeting");
appointment.Add("start_time", "2014-11-19T23:37:00+01:00");
appointment.Add("end_time", "2014-11-27T02:37:00+01:00");
appointment.Add("location", "somewhere");
appointment.Add("is_all_day_event", false);
appointment.Add("reminder_time", 15); //minutes
appointment.Add("availability", "free");
appointment.Add("visibility", "public");
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry, I miss it :-)